# Spyder did not respond when execution code in the second time

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

For example，when I run the code below it will show an image, then I close the image and run again, and no image will be shown.

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("d:\\1.png")

cv2.imshow("1",img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the code ran previously is not ended. Add `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` at the end of code, and you should press some key to end the code (don't click close button).